# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

following are code

```
NSDictionary *post = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"signup",@"methodName",_tfName.text,@"name",_tfNickName.text,@"nickname",
        _dateOfBirth.text, @"birth_date",
        @"1",@"gender",
        _tfEmail.text,@"email",
                          _tfPassword.text,@"password",
                          _tfContact.text, @"mobile",
                          _tfCountry.text,@"country",


                          @"Normal",@"social_provider",
                          @"",@"social_accesstoken",@"3",@"sponsor_choice" ,_tfPinCode.text,@"pincode",@"",
                                 @"fromLogin",nil];
```

This is actual Process of Posting data

```
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abc@login.php"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request setHTTPBody:postdata];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }


}
```

DeleGates Of URLConnection

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
    {
        //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
        [responseData appendData:data];


    }
```

Here i am Getting value Of Response Data

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Did Fail");
    }
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Did Finish");



       NSError *error = nil;
       NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

       NSLog(@"Array: %@", jsonArray);
        // Do something with responseData
    }
```

Actually i am getting value of jsonarray as nil. Even i getting value of response Data Coming From Server.

Comment: Could you log in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`: `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: it shows HTML content

Comment: And the content seems valid (I mean, the data returned is correct, not in a formatted way, but do they have sense)? Then it's not JSON. If you test with POSTMan (or something similar), does your service responds JSON?

Answer (score 1):

If i Post data Synchronously then i Got response and Even I got JSON

```
NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        if (!err)
        {
            //Getting response from server
            NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

            NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);
        }
```